# The color bar can't be fully shown when I save the figure

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Take the Code which I learned from [PyHOGS](http://pyhogs.github.io/colormap-examples.html) follows as as an example:

```
 cmap = plt.cm.Spectral

 # Generate some fake data
 N = 100
 nlines = 10
 x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, N) 
 y = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, nlines)

 # Use np.newaxis to create [N,1] and [1,Nlines] x and y arrays
 # Then broadcasting to generate Z with shape [N,Nlines]
 z = np.sin(x[:,np.newaxis] + y[np.newaxis,:]/4)

 # Use 0-1 values to generate the colors with the linspace method
 line_colors = cmap(np.linspace(0,1,nlines))


 # because the custom axes generation is the only way I've
 # figured out.
 from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
 fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,6))
 nrows = 2
 gs = GridSpec(nrows,2,width_ratios=[50,1])
 ax = [plt.subplot(gs[i,0]) for i in range(nrows)]
 cbax1 = plt.subplot(gs[1,1])

 # First, plot lines w/ legend
 a = ax[0]
 a.set_title('Labeling with a legend')

 for i in range(nlines):
      a.plot(x, z[:,i], c=line_colors[i],lw=3,label='{:4.1f}'.format(y[i]))
      leg = a.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), ncol=2)
      leg.set_title('Y')

 # Next, plot with colorbar
 a = ax[1]
 a.set_title('Labeling with a "continuous" colorbar')

 for i in range(nlines):
     a.plot(x, z[:,i], c=line_colors[i],lw=3,label='{:3.1f}'.format(y[i]))

 # Generate fake ScalarMappable for colorbar
 sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap,     norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=y[0],vmax=y[-1]))
 sm.set_array([])  # You have to set a dummy-array for this to work...
 cbar = plt.colorbar(sm, cax=cbax1)
 cbar.set_label('Y')
 cbar.set_ticks(y)
 cbar.set_ticklabels(['{:4.1f}'.format(yi) for yi in y]) # Make 'em nicer-looking

 # Moves colorbar closer to main axis by adjusting width-spacing between subplot     axes.
 fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05, hspace=0.4)

 # Set axis limits
 for a in ax:
     a.set_xlim(-np.pi, np.pi)

 plt.savefig("./POP_LULC/example_colorbar.png")
```

When I save it as .png or .pdf, the figure can't show entirely, some information on colorbar (a) has missing, like follows:
http://i5.tietuku.com/1701d9dcd4e5f24a.png

And that's My problem, wish for your kindly guide!

After using

```
    plt.tight_layout().
```

This is my next  example :

- The screencut in jupyter notebook
  http://i12.tietuku.com/f43490f03407695d.png
- Saved png:
  http://i12.tietuku.com/f9faed607cac0a7a.png

The legend on the right of figure can't show entirely even I enlarge the L/h ？

Comment: The images are no longer available. Please update your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to create some space on the right hand side for the two-column legend. You can do this with the [`subplots_adjust`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust) call you already have in there. As well as setting the `hspace` and `wspace`, `subplots_adjust` can also change the subplot locations and margins, using the kwargs `left`, `right`, `bottom` and `top`.

You just need to set the `right` argument. In this case, I found setting it to `0.8` works well.

```
 fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05, hspace=0.4, right=0.8)
```

[image]